# Error while installing Google Cloud SDK in Cygwin : Unable to fetch https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/components-2.json

Tags: python, windows, cygwin, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

While installing the Google cloud SDK in Cygwin, I'm getting the error.

```
If you are developing an App Engine application, please select the
language your application is written in.  This will install the
required tools and runtimes for working in that language.  If
necessary, you can add and remove languages later through the gcloud
component manager.
  [1]  Java
  [2]  Python and PHP
  [3]  Go
  [4]  No App Engine (you can install App Engine tools later)
Please enter your numeric choice (4):  1
```

**(gcloud.components.update) Unable to fetch https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/components-2.json**

I appreciate any help..

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? If yes, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197904/how-do-i-use-cygwin-behind-the-corporate-firewall