# Cygwin Google Cloud SDK Install Error 111

Tags: cygwin, google-compute-engine

I'm receiving the below error at work (with a proxy) when running the Google Cloud SDK install script (gcloud.components.update) Unable to fetch /components-2.json

I've viewed this thread
[Error while installing Google Cloud SDK in Cygwin : Unable to fetch https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/components-2.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041409/error-while-installing-google-cloud-sdk-in-cygwin-unable-to-fetch-https-dl-g)

I've added in the proxy information and I can download the installer (if I don't set the proxy I can't access this). 
curl /dl/cloudsdk/release/install_google_cloud_sdk.bash | bash

I can run curl https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/components-2.json

I'm running Python 2.7 and I'm on Windows XP. If its a proxy issue why can I download the files and access the page but can't run the login script?

I can download a local version of components-2.json I can also download all of the files that this file refers to.

Is there a config file I can edit to get it to look at the local versions of these files?

I can seems to find where the address /components-2.json is specified.

Cheers and thanks,

Rohan
PS sorry I couldn't include more than 2 links as I don't have a reputation, even though posting requirement mentions to show research.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, please try the following:

1. Download [`google-cloud-sdk.zip`](https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.zip) or [`google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz`](https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz)
2. Unpack the archive
3. Run the `./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh` script

This is described in small print on the [Google Cloud SDK page](https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/), underneath the text box that suggests running the command you're likely using:

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```