# How can I pass proxy authentication to cygwin installer

Tags: windows, proxy, cygwin

The setup file `setup-x86_64.exe` needs proxy info to download things in the installation process, but I'm under a proxy with authentication. **How can I authenticate proxy in order to install?**

According to this [page](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.cli), I can pass the `-p` arg to `setup-x86_64.exe`, but I tried something in this format: `http://username:password@host:port/`, and It didn't work (perhaps because asks only for `host:port`).

Note that my question is different from this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197904/how-do-i-use-cygwin-behind-the-corporate-firewall). I still don't have cygwin installed.

Comment: Have you tried use `System Proxy Setting` on `Select Connection Type` window ?