# Proxy authentication using wget on cygwin

Tags: unix, proxy, cygwin, wget

My institute recently installed a new proxy server for our network. I am trying to configure my `Cygwin` environment to be able to run `wget` and download data from a remote repository.

Browsing the internet I have found two different solutions to my problem, but no one of them seem to work in my case.

The first one I tried was to follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346649/how-do-i-force-wget-to-use-a-proxy-server-without-modifying-system-files), so in Cygwin:

```
cd /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/etc/
nano wgetrc
```

at the end of the file, I added:

```
use_proxy = on
http_proxy=http://username:password@my.proxy.ip:my.port/
https_proxy=https://username:password@my.proxy.ip:my.port/
ftp_proxy=http://username:password@my.proxy.ip:my.port/
```

(of course, using my user and password)

The second approach was what was suggested by [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197904/how-do-i-use-cygwin-behind-the-corporate-firewall), so in my Cygwin environment:

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@my.proxy.ip:my.port/
export https_proxy=https://username:password@my.proxy.ip:my.port/
export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@my.proxy.ip:my.port/
```

in both cases, if I try to test my wget, I get the following:

```
$ wget http://www.google.com
--2020-01-30 12:12:22--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving my.proxy.ip (my.proxy.ip)... 10.1XX.XXX.XX
Connecting to my.proxy.ip (my.proxy.ip)|10.1XX.XXX.XX|:8XXX... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 407 Proxy Authentication Required
2020-01-30 12:12:22 ERROR 407: Proxy Authentication Required.
```

It looks like if my user and password are not ok, but I actually checked them on my browsers and my credentials work just fine.

Any idea on what this could be due to?

Comment: have you tried as mentioned in the man pages `--proxy-user=user`   `--proxy-password=password`

Comment: hi @matzeri, thanks for your help. Since this was not getting attention in SO, I posted also in another community (that actually found it out of topic - sob! - but put me in the right direction). You can find the solution to my problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206863/proxy-authentication-using-wget-on-cygwin). Basically instead of editing the global configuration file `wgetrc`, I should have created a new `.wgetrc` in my home directory.

Comment: @Nemesi You can write this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Bodo. You are right, I';ll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved thanks to the suggestion of a User of the community [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206863/proxy-authentication-using-wget-on-cygwin).

Basically, instead of editing the global configuration file `wgetrc`, I should have created a new `.wgetrc` with my proxy configuration in my `Cygwin` home directory.

In summary:

Step 1 - Create a `.wgetrc` file;

```
nano ~/.wgetrc
```

Step 2 - record in this file the proxy info:

```
use_proxy=on
http_proxy=http://my.proxy.ip:my.port
https_proxy=https://my.proxy.ip:my.port
ftp_proxy=http://my.proxy.ip:my.port
proxy_user=username
proxy_password=password
```